# adal.js - can I use adal.js on a non-SPA MVC site?

Tags: authentication, adal.js

adal.js - can I use adal.js on a non-SPA MVC site?

From the below links, it looks like adal.js can be used on single page applications (SPA):
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/

adal.js - can I use adal.js on a non-SPA MVC site?

Answer (score 1):

Adal.js is designed for SPA applications only. The tokens are sent as a fragment which I don't think is applicable for a non-SPA site. Thers is another flavor of adal available that works well for a non-SPA mvc site: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet